# Unable to expand rows after destroy and reload; Cannot read property '_detailsShow' of undefined;

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using the jQuery [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) for creating a web page. I have a use case where the page opens with the table already populated. Now, there is a form in the page where he can put some filters and refresh the table. Also, more importantly for each row, I can expand to see more details as [explained here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

In my case, as soon as the data is reloaded after the form is submit, the details button which would expand each data row stops working. It gives the following error:

jquery.dataTables.min.js:120 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_detailsShow' of undefined

I am reloading thee table by first clearing, destroying and then calling the DataTable method. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../static/css/chosen/bootstrap-chosen.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(
                function ()
                {
                    var dashboard_table_id = "#example";

                    function destroy_existing_data_table()
                    {
                        var existing_table = $(dashboard_table_id).dataTable();
                        if (existing_table != undefined)
                        {
                            existing_table.fnClearTable();
                            existing_table.fnDestroy();
                        }
                    }

                    function create_dashboard_table()
                    {
                        var data_table = $(dashboard_table_id).DataTable({
                            "data": [{
                                "dt_RowId": 10,
                                "column1": "delhivery",
                                "column2": "CRP12345",
                                "column3": "1122",
                                "column4": "One expanded row"
                            }, {
                                "dt_RowId": 2,
                                "column1": "delhivery",
                                "column2": "CRP12345",
                                "column3": "1122",
                                "column4": "Other expanded row"
                            }],
                            "columns": [
                                {"className": "select-checkbox", orderable: false, "data": null, "defaultContent": ""},
                                {"class": "details-control", "orderable": false, "data": null, "defaultContent": ""},
                                {"data": "column1"},
                                {"data": "column2"},
                                {"data": "column3"}
                            ],
                            "buttons": {},
                            "dom": 'lBfrtip',
                            "select": {
                                "style": 'multi',
                                "selector": 'td:first-child'
                            },
                            "oLanguage": {"sSearch": ""},
                            "order": [[2, 'asc']],
                            "bLengthChange": false,
                            "pageLength": 25
                        });

                        // adding event listener for opening and closing details
                        $(dashboard_table_id).find('tbody').on('click', 'tr td.details-control',
                                function ()
                                {
                                    var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');
                                    var row = data_table.row(tableRow);

                                    if (row.child.isShown())
                                    {
                                        tableRow.removeClass('details');
                                        row.child.hide();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var rowData = row.data();
                                        tableRow.addClass('details');
                                        row.child("Hello there, this is the expanded view I am referring to....").show();
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    $("#example-form-submit").click(function (event)
                    {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        destroy_existing_data_table();
                        create_dashboard_table();
                    });

                    create_dashboard_table();
                });

    </script>
    <style>td.details-control {
        background: green;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    tr.details td.details-control {
        background: blue;
    }</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-content lfloat">
    <div class="container" style="width: 100%;">

        <label for="example-form-submit" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" id="example-form-submit" class="btn btn-primary">Refresh and try to expand</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <table id="example" class="row-border hover order-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>column1</th>
                    <th>column2</th>
                    <th>column3</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can some one please point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks a ton in advance. This has been bugging me for some time now.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5mdcrup/) : Credits: @Edis Golubich

Comment: @Edis Golubich: It is reproducible there also. Please click on the green  button. You'll see that the row expands. Now click on the button at the top. And then again click on the green button. it won't expand.

Comment: my bad. was looking for the wrong issue.

Comment: No problem. Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 8):

it works for me. just remove the latest click event handler by add .off before add the new one.

```
$(dashboard_table_id).find('tbody').off('click', 'tr td.details-control'); 
$(dashboard_table_id).find('tbody').on('click', 'tr td.details-control',function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `data_table` object is not getting 'updated' when using jQuery.on() via delegated event handling.

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/f5mdcrup/4/

What I did was declare `data_table` outside of the function. The scope will be different in this case.

Comment: I am not able to expand the rows on click even before I click the submit button.

Comment: @OneMoreError that was a different issue. You had the .on() inside the function and it got called multiple times as the function get's called as well. Adding same event handler on and on again :) I've updated the link. PS: it worked for me because I had an alert inbetween the calls. Removed it for estatics before posting, that is why it didn't for you. PPS: I should have seen this before :P

Comment: @Edis : Plunker is cool,but i am facing another issue,when i am clicking on 'Referesh and Try to Expand button' i dont want to loose my expanded state.Can you please help,Thanku..

Answer (score 1):

Following code works for me

```
$(dashboard_table_id).find('tbody').off('click', 'tr td.details-control');
$(dashboard_table_id).find('tbody').on('click', 'tr td.details-control',function(){
//Action To perform
});
```